# Ubuntu on Hyper-V and VHDX

Tags: lvm, ext4, hyper-v

I have a setup where I will run a Ubuntu Server on two VHDX disks.
System 50GB and Data 4TB. They are located on a mirrored Storage Spaces Pool and are dynamic expanded.

During the Ubuntu installation the system disk got created on first VHDX as a EXT4 on a LVM pool.

Is it a good idea to use LVM on Linux?  Or should I just use simple EXT4 on system and / or data-disk?

Just a `mkfs`, file system creation of the Data-disk to EXT4 result in a 60GB expanded VHDX-file.

```
mkfs -t ext4 -E lazy_itable_init=1 /dev/sdb1
```

I created the machine before I read about the “VHDX Block Sizes”. So maybe that's a reason…
http://www.altaro.com/hyper-v/understanding-working-vhdx-files/

What are your thoughts?